# scrape dechtech website using python

Tags: javascript, python, screen-scraping

I am looking for a way to scrape the data from this website: http://www.dectech.org/football/index.php preferably using Python. The difficulty that I seem to be having is that the data is not hard-coded into the HTML of the website, and appears to be wrapped in something called a mochi-kit ( http://mochi.github.com/mochikit/ ).

I've done some research and it seems that something like `BeautifulSoup` might be useful to me, but I think I may not be using it correctly. I've also tried using `urllib` to parse the website with no joy.

My ultimate goal is to have a program that monitors the dectech website and when new predictions are released, automatically picks out value bets using the `Betfair API`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the data is being loaded by javascript from this url

> http://www.dectech.org/cgi-bin/new_site/GetUpcomingGames.pl?divID=0

which returns

```
{
   "games" : [
      {
         "apct" : 0.377838,
         "dpct" : 0.263445,
         "expGoalDiff" : -0.04086,
         "awayID" : "6",
         "homeID" : "17",
         "date" : "20/10/2012",
         "away" : "Chelsea",
         "home" : "Tottenham",
         "hpct" : 0.358717
      },
      {
         "apct" : 0.237829,
         "dpct" : 0.250146,
         "expGoalDiff" : 0.594234,
         "awayID" : "1",
         "homeID" : "8",
         "date" : "20/10/2012",
         "away" : "Aston Villa",
         "home" : "Fulham",
         "hpct" : 0.512025
      }, /* shortened for brevity */
```

So you're incredibly lucky, you don't need to scrape the data (which is tricky), you just need to retreive it and parse it like they're doing with mochi.

Python's [simplejson](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) module would be able to parse it...

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful! That's exactly what I was looking for. Incidentally if anyone else is interested just using http://www.dectech.org/cgi-bin/new_site/GetUpcomingGames.pl gives you all the upcoming matches.